# Securing encryption algorithm in node js?

Tags: node.js, express

We are using crypto package in our node js app. The thing is we do not want the developer to know about the encryption algorithm we implemented. However, the developer would be knowing the encryption algorithm and the encryption key as they can view the source code of the encryption algorithm.

So my question is: is it possible to compile the encryption algorithm into a file like dll(.NET) or jar file (java) and include it in the project (open source solution). If not, how to prevent developer from viewing the source code?

The final expectation is the developer will know we use crypto package, but do not know we use what algorithm and key we implemented.

Note: I do not expect solution of restricting file access to the user nor hosting it in another environment.

Comment: you can use services like [JScrambler](https://jscrambler.com/en/)  to scramble code

Answer (score 0):

**node-ffi** is a Node.js addon for loading and calling dynamic libraries using pure JavaScript. It can be used to create bindings to native libraries without writing any C++ code.

https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi